# pythonic manner of merging last three columns into a single pipe seperated column

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv that has several columns. I need the middle columns to be merged into one column seperated by pipes

How would i go about doing that that?

**Example Data:**

```
B032CN517,TRUE,Men's 4.2 oz. Long-Sleeve
 Henley,"""1151|0|5"";""994|6|47"";""964|48|-1"";",0.47,Broder,3150,,22.60,2XL,0,BLACK,Canvas,,,B032CN517,http://www.broderbros.com/images/bro/prodDetail/3150_51_p.jpg,Apparel,Activewear,Henleys
& Jerseys
```

**Desired output**

```
B032CN517,TRUE,Men's 4.2 oz. Long-Sleeve
 Henley,"""1151|0|5"";""994|6|47"";""964|48|-1"";",0.47,Broder,3150,,22.60,2XL,0,BLACK,Canvas,,,B032CN517,http://www.broderbros.com/images/bro/prodDetail/3150_51_p.jpg,Apparel|Activewear|Henleys
& Jerseys
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you'll use the CSV module to read in that line, which will give a list of all the comma-delimited items in that line.

Then it's very simple:

```
line = line[:-3] + ['|'.join(line[-3:])]
```